# Laravel syntax to get query with distinct results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two MySQL tables :

```
+-----------+    +-----------+
| id.Table1 |    | id.Table2 |
+-----------+    +-----------+
|         1 |    |         2 |
|         2 |    |         3 |
|         3 |    |         4 |
|         4 |    +-----------+
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

I want to get a query with this result:

```
+-----------+
| id.Table1 |
+-----------+
|         1 |
|         5 |
+-----------+
```

How do I do it?

Comment: My code works fine, I just didn't come up with what sql querie  should I use. Anyway, I got the  desired result now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `NOT IN` clause:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE1 as a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TABLE2 as b where a.ID=b.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by using `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check. The working query is:

```
SELECT T1.Id
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL
```